# How to keep a reference to a timer in a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

React has the `useRef` that allows me to hold onto a reference to an object. I'm trying to start a repeated call to an api using a timer.  When the user clicks stop, I want to stop the repeated call, or "unsubscribe".

`subscription = timer(0,1000).subscribe(n => dispatch(fetchData()));`
`subscription.unsubscribe();`

Those functions are from the [rxjs library](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription)

Is there a way that I can do that in my `function onSubmit()` (which is inside a function component) using the `useRef` function of React to maintain a reference to subscription so that I can unsubscribe?

```
function onSubmit(){ 
    /// if 
     subscription = timer(0,1000).subscribe(n => dispatch(fetchData()));
    ///else 
     subscription.unsubscribe();

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `useRef()` in a component or in a hook.  You cannot use it just in a stand alone JS function.

Assuming your `onSubmit` is defined inside a component then you could do something like:

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';

// ...

export const MyComponent = (props) => {

  const subscription = useRef(null);

  function onSubmit() { 
    if (subscription.current === null) {
     subscription.current = timer(0,1000).subscribe(n => dispatch(fetchData()));
    } else {
     subscription.current.unsubscribe();
     subscription.current = null;
    }
  }

  // ...
};
```